# Opacity affects the way elements are hidden by another element

Tags: html, css

I was playing with the opacity attribute and wrote the following code:

```css
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: left;
}
.inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.item:hover .inner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanted the `inner` div to show up and cover its parent `item` div when its parent `item` div is hovered. Because all the other `item` divs are set to be transparent to show through the `inner` div and only the hovered `item` div's opacity is changed to 1, I expected only the hovered `item` to be covered. However, all the `item` divs before the hovered one are also hidden. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with absolute positioning: it's relative to "containing block", which is not the parent, but the ascendent element with a non-static position (in your case, the `#outer` element).

Simply addd `position: relative` to `.item`, and it will become the containing box.

Note that this has nothing to do with opacity.

Working snippet:

```css
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.item:hover .inner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the red .inner div to overlap with the pink #outer div and that's why I set the #outer to be the containing block. What puzzles me is why does .inner cover whichever .item div before its immediate parent but not the .item divs following its parent.

Comment: Your .inner divs are absolutely positioned, so they all cover the whole #outer div. But the rendering order is still dictated by order in the DOM, so any of your .inner divs would be drawn "after" (and thus on top of) any elements before it, but "before" (and thus "under") any elements after it. If you want this to work differently, you'll need to use `z-index`.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I don't quite understand what exactly you're trying to achieve? Could you give more details and/or a picture of what you want?

Comment: I asked another question which better explains what really confuses me and perhaps you can take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068718/absolutely-positioned-element-hides-the-transparent-element-before-it

Answer (score 0):

I've used some and inspired jquery tabs to make it easier

```js
$(function(){
 
  $('.item').hover(
   function(e){
   
    $('.item').removeClass('hover')
      $(this).addClass('hover')
      
    $('.content').removeClass('show') 
  var content = $(this).attr('data')
      $(content).addClass('show')
      
  },
  function(e){
    $('.item').removeClass('hover')
      $('.content').removeClass('show') 
  }
  
  )
})
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn{
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   z-index:2
}
.btn .item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.item.hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content.show{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
   <div class="btn">
      <div class="item" data="#content1"></div>
      <div class="item" data="#content2"></div>
      <div class="item" data="#content3"></div>
      <div class="item" data="#content4"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="content" id='content1'>content 1
  </div>
  <div class="content"  id='content2'>content 2
  </div>
  <div class="content"  id='content3'>content 3
  </div>
  <div class="content" id='content4'>content 4
  </div>
</div>
```