# Absolutely positioned element hides the transparent element before it

Tags: html, css

I have three block elements next to each other, the first and last are transparent and the middle one is absolutely positioned:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.box1 {
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.box2 {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
.box3 {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
```

Because `.box1` and `.box3` are set to be `opacity:0.5`, I thought they would both show through `.box2`, but only `.box3` does. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z-index` (the biggest number is on the top, and the lowest is on the down).

**Learn more :**

- [Adding z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

> This property is assigned with an integer value (positive or negative), which represents the position of the element along the z-axis. If you are not familiar with the z-axis, imagine the page has several layers one above the other. Each layer is numbered. A layer with a greater number is rendered above layers with smaller numbers.

---

```css
.box {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.box1 {
  z-index:20;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.box2 {
  z-index:10;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
.box3 {
  z-index:30;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Box2 as a role of container in your example.

To resolve this, you have to change the DOM structure.
This is not the only one solution nevertheless the better I think.

```css
.box-container {
  background: red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.box1 {
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.box2 {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
</div>
```